# explain differences between two different updates

Tags: sql, vbscript, ado

I have 2 different update queries, one I created:

```
UPDATE_QUERY = ""
UPDATE_QUERY = UPDATE_QUERY & "UPDATE ORGBHVTasklist "
UPDATE_QUERY = UPDATE_QUERY & "SET TaskID = NULL "
UPDATE_QUERY = UPDATE_QUERY & "WHERE TaskID = ? "

set cmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = objCon
cmd.CommandText = UPDATE_QUERY

set paramID = cmd.CreateParameter("@id", 3, 1, , taskID)

cmd.Parameters.Append paramID

cmd.execute
```

my colleague preferred this one:

```
UPDATE_QUERY = ""
UPDATE_QUERY = UPDATE_QUERY & "SELECT taskid "
UPDATE_QUERY = UPDATE_QUERY & "FROM ORGBHVTasklist "
UPDATE_QUERY = UPDATE_QUERY & "Where taskID = "&taskID&" "
    
set objUpdate = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objUpdate.CursorType = 2
objUpdate.LockType = 3
objUpdate.Open UPDATE_QUERY, objCon

objUpdate.Fields("taskid") = NULL
objUpdate.Update

objUpdate.close
Set objUpdate = nothing
```

He can't explain which one should be better and neither can I.
The only difference I have, is that the update on the second query crashes when there are no results to update.

Can anyone explain what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum it up:

The first approach (parameterized query/prepared statement) is [best](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/), because it

1. is easy: automagical quoting and formatting of the parameters
2. can be more efficient: the DBMS may optimize
3. avoids fetching and storing the resultset (@Ansgar)
4. scales better: would work for many records without change
5. guards against SQL-Injection

The second approach is worse because not having features 1 - 5 and worst/naive because not checking for an empty recordset (@peter, @Cageman).

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is what SQL code the vbscript environment is sending down to the DB. In the 1st query, the SQL is clear, you do a simple UPDATE. In the 2nd query - you need to find out the exact SQL code sent from vbscript to the DB probably by running a trace, setting up some lower-level logging, or something similar. My guess is that the 2nd query is looping and in the loop doing an UPDATE for each given ID, but without checking if the record set is not empty (and that's why it fails).